# how can I fetch 300K records from PHP MySQL server without LIMIT?

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, fetch

I am getting error while execute fetch query

error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contact";
$connection->query($query);
```

Please help me to solve internal server issue!

Comment: We're not really here to help with this kind of problem. Mainly because there can me a 1000 different things that result in a 500 error

Comment: If it helps, a 5xx error means 'something wrong on server'. So maybe the table doesn't exists, or a typo somewhere, or out of memory.

Comment: I suggest you turn on error reporting to get the exact error, or check your error log for said error